# R - characterise elements of an array

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array `A` ad I want to label its elements according to which interval of the distribution they belong to (0 to 20, 20 to 30, ...). What is the best way to do that in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to do this:

```
A <- c(2, 3, 5, 10, 21, 23, 7, 14)
cut(A, c(0, 20, 30))
# [1] (0,20]  (0,20]  (0,20]  (0,20]  (20,30] (20,30] (0,20]  (0,20] 
# Levels: (0,20] (20,30]
```

Comment: Thanks! My `A` is an array from a matrix; with the code below I got the error `x' must be numeric`. What should I fix? This is the piece of code I am using: `A <- data1[,1, drop=FALSE]
cut(A, c(0, 20, 30, 40, 200))`

Comment: I solved my problem using `as.matrix`: `A <- as.matrix(data[,1, drop=FALSE])`